# Inequality $|P(z)|\geq P(|z|)$ related to Mandelbrot set

Tags: inequality, polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $(P_n(z))_{n\geq 1}$ be the sequence of polynomials defined by

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
P_0(z) &=& 0 \\
P_{n+1}(z) &=& P_n(z)^2-z
\end{array}
$$

It is related to the Mandelbrot set. I have checked for $n\leq 6$ that

**Conjecture.** When $z\in{\mathbb C}, |z|\geq 2$ and $n\geq 0$, we have
$|P_n(z)|\geq P_n(|z|)$.

Can anyone prove or disprove this conjecture ?

**What I did**: put $r=|z|$. The number $u=\frac{z}{r}$ has modulus one. Unless $u=-1$, there is a $t\in{\mathbb R}$ such that $u=\frac{(1-t^2)+2t i}{1+t^2}$. Expanding $|P_n(z)|-P_n(|z|)=\Bigg|P_n\Big(r\big(\frac{(1-t^2)+2t i}{1+t^2}\big)\Big)\Bigg|-P_n(r)$, we find that it is of the form
$\frac{A_n(r,t)}{(1+t^2)^{2^{n-1}}}$ where $A_n(r,t)$ is a polynomial. Writing $A_n(r,t)=\sum_{k=0}^N B_k(r) t^k$ where $N$ is the degree of $A_n$ with respect to $t$,
it turns out that for $n\leq 6$, each $B_k(r)$ is nonnegative when $r\geq 2$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Why turn down a sensible edit?

Comment: @jose-carlos-santos: Now I'll have to live with the inferior formatting, or edit again.

Comment: I'm logging out - I've had it for today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function of $x$ by
$$
\phi_z(x) := x^2 - z.
$$

First, we prove that $|\phi_z(x)| \ge \phi_{|z|}(|x|)$. Indeed,
$$
|\phi_z(x)| = |x^2 - z| \ge ||x|^2 - |z|| \ge \phi_{|z|}(|x|)
$$
by the second triangle inequality. Now we proceed to the desired inequality. Note the formula
$$
P_{n+1}(z) = \phi_z(P_n(z)).
$$
Hence, suppose we have proven the statement for $n$. Then
$$
|P_{n+1}(z)| = |\phi_z(P_n(z))| \ge \phi_{|z|}(|P_n(z)|) \ge \phi_{|z|}(P_n(|z|)) = P_{n+1}(|z|),
$$
where the last inequality follows from the induction hypothesis and the fact that $\phi_{|z|}$ increases monotonically on the positive reals - this follows immediately from
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \phi_z(x) = 2x.
$$
Indeed, we are restricted to the positive real numbers because $P_n(|z|) \ge |z| \ge 0$ for $|z| \ge 2$. Indeed,
$$
P_n(|z|) = P_{n-1}(|z|)^2 - |z| \overset{\text{induction}}{\ge} |z|(|z|-1) \ge |z|.
$$

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Apologies. It should now be correct.

Comment: I mean something utterly obscure.

Comment: ...see the latest edit. I changed only one little bit.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy At present, the answer is complete and correct.

Comment: Maybe you haven't reloaded the page yet?

Comment: The latter never happens, because |z| is non-negative.

Comment: ...under the assumption that |z| >= 2.

Comment: Please see my answer for a rigorous proof.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82137/discussion-between-ewan-delanoy-and-algebraicsanonymous).